# How to Access Azure SQL Server/Database from Tableau Desktop using Active Directory Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, tableau-desktop

Can someone let me know why I'm unable to access our Azure SQL Database using Tableau Desktop with our Active Directory account?

I have no problem gaining access using Username and Password, but can't access using AD account i.e. usernam@company.com

I'm getting the following errors

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have installed ODBC Driver or not. If that's the case, try installing it by following this [Download link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) depending on the operating system you are using.

After installing it, configure the ODBC DSN that may help you to resolve the error.

If it's already installed and still you are getting error, try degrading/upgrading the version.

Take a look at this similar problem answered in below reference:

[Error connecting to MySQL - Error Code: B19090E0](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000bhTkmSAE/error-connecting-to-mysql-error-code-b19090e0)

Comment: Hi Akshaya, thanks for responding. I tried your suggestion, but I'm still getting the error. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: Hi SO, has anyone else got any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the server to access using AD account https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell